# Can you avoid a 502 error when deploying a webpack build to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When deploying my server side rendered React app to a Node Elastic Beanstalk environment, the site shows a 502 error where Nginx can't get a connection during the process of running the webpack build.

In the package.json I run the following to do the build, which is triggered by Elastic Beanstalk during the deploy:

```
"prestart": "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --colors --bail"
```

and I run the following to start the server once the build is complete:

```
"start": "node dist/server.js"
```

In-between the two, the site is showing a 502 error. I have a few potential options, but I'm curious to see if anyone has solved this in a different/simpler way.

1. Build the site using AWS CodeBuild instead of an NPM script
2. Run multiple instances and do a roll out deploy
3. Run multiple environments and swap URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option you list is probably the easiest. If you change your EB configuration from "Single instance" to "Load balancing, auto scaling" and set your auto-scaling rules to have a minimum of two servers, then you'll get the desired deployment behavior for free. EB will take the instances out of the load balancer before deploying to them, ensuring that your site is never unavailable.

The third option, also known as a blue/green deployment, is more powerful (since it leaves the previous version intact for easy rollback) but might be overkill for your situation.